# Is there more than a 'double' whammy?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, phrase-requests

I have three (could grow to be more) bad reasons for a situation and I wondered if there is such a thing as a triple whammy that is an extension of the double whammy. From my research online, a triple whammy means a totally different thing. I have pasted the definition that I found in the [Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/triple+whammy), but that originally came from *McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions*:

> **triple whammy** definition:
>
> **1.** *n.* a powerful treatment; a powerful shock : *The market crash, the trade figures, and the death of the secretary of defense was a powerful triple whammy in Washington politics this week.*

Is this just a higher "degree of badness," or does it mean something different altogether?

Comment: So you ask if a word exists, and you then give that word _with_ a dictionary definition. What is your question, now that you have answered what you asked?

Comment: In the example you have given, note that there are 3 different problems that constitute the "triple whammy". I think that you can have arbitrary numbers of whammies. "Quintuple whammy" to me would mean 5 related problems, and "triple whammy" would mean 3 related problems.

Comment: The word exists but it doesn't mean what I am trying to use it for. I explained how I am trying to use the word. The definition I found isn't what I want.

Comment: What exactly do you think "double whammy" means? Because as the definition you quoted demonstrates, "triple whammy" means precisely what it sounds like it means: a double whammy, only more so.

Comment: A market crash, bad trade figures and a death aren't all blows or setbacks?

Comment: Thank you all... I have been googling what would be the correct way to say more than 2 blows or setbacks. And I see that I could use third, triple, forth etc as well... I stand corrected JakeP.

Comment: @JakeP Indeed. Or, even [no whammy](http://youtu.be/fnTbO26u9bQ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [double whammy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Whammy) can be applied to multiple things as well.

> An English expression meaning multiple (or a combination of) negative circumstances, events, or effects. Sometimes hyphenated.

---

Though triple whammy is used in the sense you want also and [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triple_whammy) has a definition:

> a threefold blow or setback (popularized in the Li'l Abner comic strip)

And it can be used as "quadruple whammy", "quintuple whammy" etc...

Comment: Yup... I can basically just slap a number before the whammy as I fancy. Thank you!!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li'l_Abner#Additions_to_the_language

Comment: @JohnLawler - Not a fan of Press Your Luck?

Comment: In a word, no. But that TV show appeared at least 30 years after Al Capp had spread the term throughout American culture.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to give you a detailed guide on how to use the word whammy.

In American slang the term whammy is highly affiliated with the old game show [Press Your Luck](http://gscentral.net/pylhista.htm).

*No whammy, no whammy, big money, big bucks, stop!*

The term and its association go hand in hand when you are speaking.

**One whammy is fine, play on.**

[image]

---

**Double whammy, maybe a little more cautious.**

[image]

---

**Triple whammy, well now you are on your last leg.**

[image]

---

**Quadruple whammy, BUZZZ! you are done.**

[image]

No one will understand quintuple whammy or anything above that, and even using quadruple is pressing your luck.